# How to implement account lockout using B2C custom flows

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using IEF Custom flows and have disabled Strong Passwords (as we had some custom password complexity rules). With Strong Passwords disabled, the lockout password protection that can be configured in B2C is also ignored.

I need to add lockout password protection to the custom flows. This would involve keeping a counter of failed logins, but I could not find a way to increment a counter. How would I go about implementing lockout password protection in a custom flow?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-smart-lockout

You can configure Lockout threshold and Lockout duration.
I have recently used this and it is working end to end perfectly.